# Determine Hermite interpolation polynomial and interpolation polynomial using linear splines

Tags: numerical-methods

y:=f(x)

```
                                               xi || -1   0    1     2  
                                               yi || 4    6    2    10
```

a) Determine Hermite interpolation polynomial and evaluate the appropriate error.

b) Determine interpolation polynomial using method of linear splines and evaluate the appropriate error.

I can find some other interpolation polynomial but don't know how to find Hermite interpolation polynomial cause the only way I can find it is when I have first and second derivation of yi, should I find it here then continue usual procedure to find Hermite interpolation or there is some other way for that?